# Adding zip as attachment to MFMailComposerViewController fail in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an application in which I'm attaching zip file to mail composer. I'm using below code to attach zip file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Records.zip"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: writableDBPath];
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"/Records.zip"];
```

File in document directory: /var/mobile/Applications/46348DAA-9B4B-4DA8-98E0-3CEF880D2721/Documents/Records.zip

I'm getting stuck in `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:WritableDBPath];` I don't know what is the issue.

When I'm able to attach zip I'm getting receive memory warning *** -[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1cd04690.

Please help me.

Comment: Please check the zip file is there or not. `NSLog` the `data`. I think it's null

Comment: Side note: You should follow a coding style, for ObjC they usually tell you to use variable names that start with lower case. [Example ObjC style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Variable_Names)

Comment: Hi @MidhunMP It showing me file size greater than 0.

Comment: Sorry for coding style I'll correct it.

Comment: HI I'm using ZipArchive to zip the folder....is it good? Means workable?

Comment: *** -[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _cancelUnconditionallyThen:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e951b40

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same code for another device and its working fine. I think that was the device issue. I have tried with two new devices and its working fine.